# GIT Checkout - Switch Submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

I have a project with a **master** and **staging** branch. 
The project has a submodule which also had a **master** and **staging** branch.

My .gitmodules file has referenced the branch correctly so e.g. my project on branch **master** has the following

```
[submodule "src/mysubmodule"]
    path = src/mysubmodule
    url = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/mysubmodule.git
    branch = master
```

and the branch **staging** has

```
[submodule "src/mysubmodule"]
    path = src/mysubmodule
    url = https://username@bitbucket.org/username/mysubmodule.git
    branch = staging
```

I want to switch the branch of my submodule(s) as well if i switch the branch of my project. `git checkout master` etc.

Comment: `git submodule update`?

Comment: No, does not switch the submodules branch

Comment: `git submodule update` has additional [flags available](https://devdocs.io/git/git-submodule). "The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on command line options and the value of `submodule.<name>.update` configuration variable." I might be wrong, but I think checkout is what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

The `submodule.<id>.branch` configuration is just a hint for `git submodule update --remote` or `... --rebase`.  It will be ignored by the default `--checkout` operation.

You have to update the submodules of the "staging" branch manually (e.g. by `git submodle update --remote`) and commit these changes then.